# Return group including zero entries in MongoDB aggregate

Tags: mongodb

All of the answers out there seem to be pretty old, so I'll bring this up again:

I am trying to group and count a collection by date likes this:

```
db.getCollection('mycollection').aggregate([
  {
    $group : {
               _id :{ $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$timestamp"} },
               count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  }
])
```

which works pretty good, even on large collections, except it doesn't return dates with zero counts. Whats best practice to approach this today? Is there a way to do this in aggregate?

Of cause I could always create an array of dates and loop through it one by one, but that seems pretty expensive performancewise, so there must be a better way, right?

Or: Match the aggregation against an array with all dates from first to last entry in the collection and add those not present?

Comment: So if your `timestamp` field has values from 2015 to 2020, Do you need 0's on all missing dates over a period of 5 years ?

Comment: In fact: Yes. I really simplified my code here and will of cause reduce my output by putting a $match in front of the $group, but it doesn't change the issue. Any particular reason you're asking?

Comment: Yes using `$match` should help you a lot, otherwise generating all days between two given dates(for couple of years) can be huge, I would say even though you do it for an year it can become cumbersome when it's done via mongo(Cause you need to consider no.of days for a month say 31 for Jan in next step add `0` to missing dates. Additionally you might need to know 2020 Feb has 29 days - So doing all of this in query can be very tricky) :-)

Comment: So, do you have a solution for the zero problem? The aggregation up top takes only about 3 seconds for over a million documents and about three years of data, so thats clearly not my problem.

Comment: not getting anything on top of my mind, not sure how to get feb2020 has 29 days *(Vs)* feb2019 has 28 days..So this kind of stuff makes your simple aggregation look bulky when it's done over 3years..

Comment: Well, new Date()? Maybe I wasn't clear about this. My only problem is that this $group statement won't return anything at all if the count is zero, so if I wanted to use this data for say a graph displaying a given timeframe, this will actually turn out to be very wrong (e.g. with February having only 18 days in the data, because the rest of the days have a count of zero)

Comment: Yes that's what I'm saying `$group` will group on existing days, When you want 0's for non-existing days in a month do it would be very tricky in mongo as you need to know total days in a month & get missing dates to assign 0's..

Answer (score 2):

It seems, there is still no way to do this in MongoDB, so here is my solution on how to group a collection by day, count the resulting documents and restructure the output so it contains all days including those with a count of zero.

Fetch your data from the collection:

```
db.getCollection('mycollection').aggregate([{
    $match : { 
       timestamp: {"$gte": new Date(2020, 1, 2), "$lt": new Date(2020, 2, 1)}}
   },
   {
    $group : {
       _id :{ $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$timestamp"} },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
      }
}])
```

This will return all days in the given timeframe (february 2020) where the count is higher than zero (mongo_return in the below snippet)
To restructure the array, so it contains **all days in february**, you could do something like this:

```js
// MONGODB RESULT
var mongo_return = [
  {
    _id: "2020-02-02",
    count: 294.0
  },
  {
    _id: "2020-02-16",
    count: 243.0
  },
  {
    _id: "2020-02-18",
    count: 153.0
  }
];

// INSERT MONGODAYS INTO ARRAY
var mongoDays = mongo_return.map(function(item) {
  return item._id;
});

// SET TIMEFRAME
var start = new Date(2020, 1, 1);
var end = new Date(2020, 2, 0);

// PRODUCE ALL DAYS IN TIMEFRAME
for (var d = start; d <= end; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
  let MyDate = new Date(d);
  let MyDateString =
    MyDate.getFullYear() +
    "-" +
    ("0" + (MyDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +
    "-" +
    ("0" + MyDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
  // CHECK IF DAY IS IN MONGODAYS
  // AND ADD TO MONGORESULT WITH ZERO IF NOT
  if (!mongoDays.includes(MyDateString))
    mongo_return.push({ _id: MyDateString, count: 0 });
}

// ORDER ARRAY
const result = mongo_return.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a._id < b._id ? -1 : a._id > b._id ? 1 : 0;
});

console.log(result);
```

This surely works, but will come at a penalty, the larger the datasets get.
If you have a better solution, please post it. However: This is not about js, I know the above script can be shortend, but thats not my question. I want to know if and how this is possible in MongoDB by some sort of flag or option or workaround.

I can't believe this is supposed to be this complicated.